# There is no eth0 when I input ifconfig

Tags: pi-3, linux, networkmanager

I'm uing Raspberry Pi3 but I could not see ethp when I input ifconfig.
I can only see 
enxb827eb844b0c : xxx
lo: xxx

Answer (score 1):

This is **NORMAL** for `Stretch`.

You do not need to do anything, the Pi should work as normal.

If you want to understand **WHY** and for other options see [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

PS There is no need to be coy about posting the **full output** from `ifconfig`, which is necessary if you actually need help with troubleshooting.

Comment: interesting, my raspbian stretch still shows eth0:

Comment: @JaromandaX Did you do a clean install?

Comment: Ahh, of course not :p

Answer (score 1):

The string "**enxb827eb844b0c**" consists of your Ethernet card MAC address.
you can change its name to "**eth0**" as I do after installation ( using a script ).

Using command line, locate eth alias in file

/lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules:

```
grep -o 'NAME=".*' /lib/udev/rules.d/73-usb-net-by-mac.rules | grep -o'".'
```

Use any text editor, `nano` or `gedit` to change its name.

Comment: Or more simply pass `net.ifnames=0` on the kernel command line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Comment: Thank you and adding net.ifnames=0 on the kernel command line in /boot/cmdline.txt fixed problem.

Comment: Or keep the new type of network name and start to learn it... Embrace the future.